# Tomcat  servlet,jsp pages from examples not rendering despite correct PATH?

Tags: java, windows, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I recently installed Java(SE) and set the PATH in system variables and could easily run Java programs. Then, I installed the free version of tomcat 7.0.5 and whenever ever I attempt to open the `http://localhost:8080`, it navigates to the Tomcat home page, but I can't get my servlet.jsp pages rendered even after setting the CATALINA_HOME system variable and the -classpath to the for servlet.jsp.

Here are the PATH and variable value in use on my system:

CATALINA_HOME:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
```

CLASSPATH:

```
.;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program 
    Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;
```

---

PATH:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin
```

---

JAVA_HOME:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24
```

---

Please help me resolve this How do I get the servlet,jsp examples up in Tomcat? I want to run some other jsp,servlet files too.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 variables that need to be set up for Tomcat to run correctly:

The approach I recommend you use is to define the 'HOME' variables before the 'PATH' and then use these to define or append your PATH:

1. Define `JAVA_HOME` with a value that targets the parent directory of the `bin`.
2. Verify this via `echo %JAVA_HOME%` from the command prompt or even better, your Java version via `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version`from the command prompt.
3. Unpack Tomcat to your choice location and then define `CATALINA_HOME` to target your unpacked directory (the one that contains Tomcat bin).
4. Verify this via `echo %CATALINA_HOME%` from the command prompt.
5. Define your `PATH` by targeting these variables and adding the `\bin\` to them with a value that looks like: `%JAVA_HOME\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;` Note that on Windows we use a `;` to seperate PATH entries unlike `:` on Linux.
6. If you set these as Syestem variables (as admin for all users), restart to allow the system to update it's values otherwise (if you used environment variables), close all command prompts and open a new one.
7. run `startup` to start Tomcat.
8. compile your Servlet to the `webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes` via:

   javac -d %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\examples\WEB-INF\classes ...\TestServlet.java
9. You should now bw able to access it from your choice browser by requesting: `http://localhost:8080/TestServlet`